# User input that generates numbers with a set amount of digits python

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way in which a person can set the amount of digits a random number can have.
In concept this is quite simple, but yet I'm struggling to find a way.

This is how the program should run:

```
digit = int(input("Input amount of digits (>=2): "))
>> 3
342
```

I need the program to run for any given input to turn into a random number using random.randint with a set amount of digits that's from the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randint

digits = int(input("Input amount of digits (>=2): "))

lo = 10 ** (digits - 1)  # ex: 100
hi = (10 ** digits) - 1  # ex: 999
num = randint(lo, hi)
```

Comment: Given that `randint` is a wrapper for `randrange`, you could simplify a bit to: `hi = lo * 10`, `num = randrange(lo, hi)`.

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint` takes 2 parameters, a minimum and a maximum value

you can use the '*' operator to "multiuply" a string

```
from random import randint
digit = int(input("Input amount of digits (>=2): "))
max = int('9' * digit)
print(randint(0, max))
```